# FastAPI - Pydantic - Value Error Raises Internal Server Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I am using FastAPI with Pydantic.

My problem - I need to raise ValueError using Pydantic

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from fastapi import Depends, HTTPException

app = FastAPI()

class RankInput(BaseModel):

    rank: int

    @validator('rank')
    def check_if_value_in_range(cls, v):
        """
        check if input rank is within range
        """
        if not 0 < v < 1000001:

            raise ValueError("Rank Value Must be within range (0,1000000)")
            #raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Rank Value Error") - this works But I am looking for a solution using ValueError
        return v

def get_info_by_rank(rank):
    return rank

@app.get('/rank/{rank}')
async def get_rank(value: RankInput = Depends()):
    result = get_info_by_rank(value.rank)
    return result
```

this piece of code gives `Internal Server Error` when a ValueError is raised

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59427 - "GET /info/?rank=-1 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 396, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 199, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 111, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 566, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 227, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 41, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 195, in app
    dependency_overrides_provider=dependency_overrides_provider,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py", line 550, in solve_dependencies
    solved = await run_in_threadpool(call, **sub_values)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 34, in run_in_threadpool
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, func, *args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 400, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for GetInput
rank
  ValueError() takes no keyword arguments (type=type_error)
ERROR:uvicorn.error:Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 396, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 199, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 111, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 566, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 227, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 41, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 195, in app
    dependency_overrides_provider=dependency_overrides_provider,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py", line 550, in solve_dependencies
    solved = await run_in_threadpool(call, **sub_values)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 34, in run_in_threadpool
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, func, *args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 400, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for GetInput
rank
  ValueError() takes no keyword arguments (type=type_error)
```

I also checked https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2180.

But I was not able to figure out a solution.

What I need to do is Raise `ValueError` with a Custom Status Code.

Note - I know I can get the Job Done by raising `HTTPException`.

But I am looking for a solution using `ValueError`

Could you tell me where I am going wrong?

Have Also Posted this Issue on Github - https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/3761

Comment: [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) is one of the basic exception classes in Python. This doesn't have any functionality to handle the status code. (But, you can do something similar by inheriting the same class)

Comment: Raising the `ValueError` obviously cause the ***Internal Server Error***, I don't understand why would you want that

Comment: I was using HTTPException itself. I was 'asked' to use ValueError.

Comment: That is so weird because I expected this to be implanted within pydantic validation :S

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're not raising an `HTTPException` then normally any other uncaught exception will generate a 500 response (an `Internal Server Error`). If your intent is to respond with some other custom error message and HTTP status when raising a particular exception - say, `ValueError` - then you can use add a global exception handler to your app:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse


@app.exception_handler(ValueError)
async def value_error_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: ValueError):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=400,
        content={"message": str(exc)},
    )
```

This will give a 400 response (or you can change the status code to whatever you like) like this:

```
{
    "message": "Value Must be within range (0,1000000)"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. what I am looking for is Something which can be used within the Models.

Comment: How is the model being used? Is it as a type hint in your route? Or are you using it in the body of a function (e.g. via parse_obj())? Can you share an example by updating your question? If it’s in the body then you can catch the ValueError there and return a valid response (or raise a HTTPException), but otherwise there’s probably no solution as any Exception raised by the model will be raised to FastAPI and without an exception handler it will respond with a 500. You can’t return a response from a model, you can only do that from your route function, an exception handler, or some middleware.

Comment: Okay thanks, your Model is being used as a Dependency. The DI system would handle a HTTPException raised from the Model validator, but anything else will result in a 500 by design. [see here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#requestvalidationerror-vs-validationerror) If you want your app to respond in a custom way from a model without using HTTPException, the only way I'm aware of is to raise a custom exception and add a custom exception handler to the app that returns a custom response. You can't return the response directly from the model though.

Answer (score 10):

Please note that `pydantic` expects that validators raise a `ValueError`, `TypeError`, or `AssertionError` (see [docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/)) which `pydantic` will convert into a `ValidationError`.

Further, as per [FastAPI's documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#override-request-validation-exceptions):

> When a request contains invalid data, FastAPI internally raises a `RequestValidationError`.

[and](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#requestvalidationerror-vs-validationerror)

> `RequestValidationError` is a sub-class of Pydantic's `ValidationError`.

The result of this is that a standard `Validation` error raised during `pydantic`'s Model validation will be translated into a `422 Unprocessable Entity`, and the response body will contain details on why the validation failed.

(As a side note: `pydantic` comes with [constrained types](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#constrained-types) which allow to constrain basic datatypes without having to write explicit validators.)

If the above is not satisfactory and you'd like to change the behaviour, here's how I would approach it (see [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#error-handling) for details on the `ValidationError` handling):

```py
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, Request, status
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from fastapi.exception_handlers import request_validation_exception_handler
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel, conint

class RankInput(BaseModel):
    # Constrained integer, must be greater than or equal to 0
    # and less than or equal to 1 million.
    rank: conint(ge=0, le=1_000_000)

async def rank_out_of_bound_handler(request: Request, exc: RequestValidationError):

    validation_errors = exc.errors()
    for err in validation_errors:
        # You could check for other things here as well, e.g. the error type.
        if "rank" in err["loc"]:
            return JSONResponse(
                status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                content={"message": "Rank must be in range [0, 1000000]."}
            )

    # Default response in every other case.
    return await request_validation_exception_handler(request, exc)

def get_info_by_rank(rank):
    return rank


app = FastAPI(
    exception_handlers={RequestValidationError: rank_out_of_bound_handler},
)

@app.get('/rank/{rank}')
async def get_rank(value: RankInput = Depends()):
    result = get_info_by_rank(value.rank)
    return result
```

A call to the endpoint now gives:

```
$ curl -i "http://127.0.0.1:8000/rank/1"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
date: Sat, 28 Aug 2021 20:47:58 GMT
server: uvicorn
content-length: 1
content-type: application/json

1
```

```
$  curl -i "http://127.0.0.1:8000/rank/-1"
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
date: Sat, 28 Aug 2021 20:48:24 GMT
server: uvicorn
content-length: 49
content-type: application/json

{"message":"Rank must be in range [0, 1000000]."}
```

```
$ curl -i "http://127.0.0.1:8000/rank/1000001"
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
date: Sat, 28 Aug 2021 20:48:51 GMT
server: uvicorn
content-length: 49
content-type: application/json

{"message":"Rank must be in range [0, 1000000]."}
```

If you were to add a different endpoint that uses the same model, the exception handler will automatically take care of this as well, e.g.:

```py
@app.get('/other-rank/{rank}')
async def get_other_rank(value: RankInput = Depends()):
    result = get_info_by_rank(value.rank)
    return result
```

```
$ curl -i "http://127.0.0.1:8000/other-rank/-1"
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
date: Sat, 28 Aug 2021 20:54:16 GMT
server: uvicorn
content-length: 49
content-type: application/json

{"message":"Rank must be in range [0, 1000000]."}
```

If this is not what you're looking for, could you explain why exactly you'd like to raise a `ValueError`?

Comment: That is so weird because I expected this to be implanted within pydantic validation :S

Comment: What exactly do you mean? What were you expecting to be part of Pydantic?

Comment: this is exactly what I needed; I needed to return a specific error code and message when there is a validation error, like missing fields.

Answer (score 2):

You've run into this FastAPI bug/discussion: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1474

You would expect that if a Pydantic model raises `ValidationError` inside a `Depends()` then FastAPI would convert this to a `RequestValidationError` just as it does if it encounters one in a model for a request body. But it doesn't. That's what the bug is about.

There are a few solutions proposed in the bug linked above.

A slightly simpler option that I prefer is to add a class method that catches `ValidationError` and wraps it into a `RequestValidationError` just as Pydantic does for a request body:

```
from pydantic.error_wrappers import ErrorWrapper

class RankInput(BaseModel):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def from_path(cls, *, rank):
        """For use in Depends when extracting a model from the path. FastAPI doesn't
        automatically create a RequestValidationError from a ValidationError during
        Depends processing: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1474
        """
        try:
            return cls(rank=rank)
        except ValidationError as ex:
            raise RequestValidationError([ErrorWrapper(ex, ("path"))])


async def get_rank(value: RankInput = Depends(RankInput.from_path)):
    ...
```

What I certainly would **not** do is implement a custom error handler for `ValueError` or `ValidationError`, or return a custom `JSONResponse` instead of raising an exception. As the FastAPI documentation says:

> if you have a Pydantic ValidationError in your response or anywhere in
> your code (not in the client's request), it's actually a bug in your
> code.[1](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#requestvalidationerror-vs-validationerror)

The same could be said to apply to `ValueError`.

And the problem with returning a custom `JSONResponse` is that you've got to do all the work of making sure it follows exactly the same format as a 422 response generated by FastAPI from a `RequestValidationError`.