# Custom validation for FastAPI's query parameter using pydatinc causes Internal Server Error

Tags: python, exception, fastapi, valueerror, pydantic

My `GET` endpoint receives a query parameter that needs to meet the following criteria:

1. be an `int` between 0 and 10
2. be even number

`1.` is straight forward using `Query(gt=0, lt=10)`. However, it is not quiet clear to me how to extend `Query` to do extra custom validation such as `2.`. The documentation ultimately leads to pydantic. But, my application runs into internal server error when the second validation `2.` fails.

Below is a minimal scoped example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Query
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, validator

app = FastAPI()

class CommonParams(BaseModel):
    n: int = Query(default=..., gt=0, lt=10)

    @validator('n')
    def validate(cls, v):
        if v%2 != 0:
            raise ValueError("Number is not even :( ")
        return v


@app.get("/")
async def root(common: CommonParams = Depends()):
    return {"n": common.n}
```

Below are requests that work as expected and ones that break:

```
# requsts that work as expected
localhost:8000?n=-4
localhost:8000?n=-3
localhost:8000?n=2
localhost:8000?n=8
localhost:8000?n=99

# request that break server
localhost:8000?n=1
localhost:8000?n=3
localhost:8000?n=5
```

Comment: Can you clarify "break server"? What error message do you get in the terminal?

Comment: You raise a ValueError, while [fastapi raises a RequestValidationError](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#override-request-validation-exceptions) when validation fails. Try raising a RequestValidationError instead and see if that is handled by the fastapi logic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FastAPI - Pydantic - Value Error Raises Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68914523/fastapi-pydantic-value-error-raises-internal-server-error)

Comment: Thank you for your input. This is not quiet what I am looking for. What I am looking for is behaviour that is similar to the `lt` and 'gt' validators but instead of checking if number is less than, it checks if number is even. For example, if input is 99 (which is not between 0 and 10) my endpoint response is `{"detail":[{"loc":["query","n"],"msg":"ensure this value is greater than 0","type":"value_error.number.not_gt","ctx":{"limit_value":0}}]}` I would like to achieve similar behaviour for checking if input is even.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1

Raise [`HTTPException`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#use-httpexception) directly instead of [`ValueError`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/), as demonstrated in Option 1 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804). Example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Query, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

app = FastAPI()

class CommonParams(BaseModel):
    n: int = Query(default=..., gt=0, lt=10)

    @validator('n')
    def prevent_odd_numbers(cls, v):
        if v % 2 != 0:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=422, detail='Input number is not even')
        return v


@app.get('/')
async def root(common: CommonParams = Depends()):
    return {'n': common.n}
```

**Server Response** (when the input number is not even, e.g., `n = 1`):

```json
# 422 Error: Unprocessable Entity

{
  "detail": "Input number is not even"
}
```

### Option 2

Use a [custom exception handler](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#install-custom-exception-handlers), in order to handle `ValueError` exceptions, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71800464/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70954531/17865804). Example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Depends, Query, status
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

app = FastAPI()

@app.exception_handler(ValueError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: ValueError):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
        content=jsonable_encoder({"detail": exc.errors(),  # optionally, include the pydantic errors
                 "custom msg": {"Your error message"}}),   # optionally, return a custom message
    )
    
class CommonParams(BaseModel):
    n: int = Query(default=..., gt=0, lt=10)

    @validator('n')
    def prevent_odd_numbers(cls, v):
        if v % 2 != 0:
            raise ValueError('Input number is not even')
        return v


@app.get('/')
async def root(common: CommonParams = Depends()):
    return {'n': common.n}
```

**Server Response** (when the input number is not even, e.g., `n = 1`):

```json
# 422 Error: Unprocessable Entity

{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "n"
      ],
      "msg": "Input number is not even",
      "type": "value_error"
    }
  ],
  "custom msg": [
    "Your error message"
  ]
}
```

#### Update

Please note that in Pydantic V2, `@validator` has been deprecated and was replaced by `@field_validator`. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71258131/17865804) for more details and examples.