# FastAPI, How to raise custom Exception from invalid null field request?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I use FastAPI version 0.87.0

And I need

- define validation function which is can access multiple field at once. like this `if name is None and number is None`

  - So I use `root_validator`
- raise custom Exception from null request, not Pydantic Error (`1 validation error for Request\nquery -> ...`)

  - So I use `root_validator(pre=True)`
- And Swagger UI display it `required`

  - So I can not define like this `Query(None)`, it must be `Query(...)`
- And it defined with custom alias field name, and description.

  - so I use `Query`, `Body` from FastAPI.

```
@router.get("/foo")
async def foo(req: FooReq):
  ...

class FooReq(BaseModel):
  required_field: str = Query(..., alias='requiredField', description='description')
  not_required_field: int | None = Query(None, alias='notRequiredField', description='description')

  @root_validator(pre=True):
  def my_validation(cls, values):
    if values.get('requiredField') is None:
      raise CustomException
```

case 1

raise CustomException fine. but Swagger display `not required`

```
required_field: str = Query(None, alias='requiredField', description='description')
required_field: str | None = Query(None, alias='requiredField', description='description')
```

case 2

the Swagger display `required` fine, but it raise `Pydantic Error`

```
required_field: str = Query(..., alias='requiredField', description='description')
required_field: str | None = Query(..., alias='requiredField', description='description')
```

how to do that?

is there any other best practice handling validation with custom exception?

Comment: You might also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75545471/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70954531/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71800464/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75998823/17865804) helpful